# print loop of results into variable

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, iteration

I have code that prints out a result like:

```
jobs = ['http://www.I-am-a-url.com','http://www.I-am-another-url.com']
```

I want to save this list in a variable called `TEXT` and `iterate` through each `list-item` when I call the variable `TEXT`

I currently have:

```
TEXT = print('Latest jobs from site:\n\n{}'.format(job for job in jobs))
```

**DESIRED**

```
>>> TEXT
>>> 'Latest jobs from site: 'http://www.I-am-a-url.com', 'http://www.I-am-another-url.com'
```

It just doesn't appear to be right, can someone help me?

Comment: make `TEXT` a function.  `TEXT = lambda: print('Latest jobs from site:\n\n{}'.format(job for job in jobs))` then call it like `TEXT()`

Comment: Print retruns `None` in Python

Comment: It would help if you could explain what you mean by "It just doesn't appear to be right"

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @Chris_Rands from print like `print(TEXT)` just the `list-items` from `jobs`

Comment: Please show the exact desired output in your question

Comment: @Chris_Rands - Please see `DESIRED`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the desired output, simply `join` the list with `', '`:

```
print('Latest jobs from site: {}'.format(', '.join(jobs)))
# Latest jobs from site: http://www.I-am-a-url.com, http://www.I-am-another-url.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to build a function that prints every time you call it.  You're close, but printing from generators doesn't work exactly as you expect.  Something like this works better

```
TEXT = lambda: print(('Latest jobs from site:\n\n{}'*len(jobs)).format(*jobs))
```

Output:

```
Latest jobs from site:

http://www.I-am-a-url.comLatest jobs from site:

http://www.I-am-another-url.com
```